# Making a "Stardew Valley" type of House/Room Customization in Unity (2D)

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

I am need of Dire help with this, mainly because I am positive I am unsure what the type of feature I am requesting is even called. But here it goes:

There is a game called Stardew Valley, and one of the key features I kind of want to include in my game is where you can Drag and Drop an Item or Fixture into any part of a room or house. I know countless games that do it, its just this one is on my mind.

Point being, I just need a Script that can do that type of Feature in Unity, C# is the choice language. Problem is, I don't even know what this type of feature is called, so I can't find reference online.

So my main points here are:

- What is this feature called?
- Whats a good Script for it? (C#)
- Will it work for for 2D games in Unity?

I am positive I am quite unsure what this is called, so having this for reference will help me out in the long run for future development.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on _"Drag and Drop an Item or Fixture into any part of a room or house"_ - so we know exactly what you want.  Anyway your question is perhaps **too broad**.  [ask]

Comment: A better example would be a Sims game, where you can build furniture and put it into the house?

Comment: I guess you could call it _interactive item placement_; or _drag and drop_.